# Functions and floating point comparison

Tags: c, function, floating-point, numerical-methods, newtons-method

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define abs(a) ((a)>0 ? a: -a)
#define eps_sqrt 0.00000000000001
#define it 100

float sqrt(float x)
/*The Square Root Function using the Newton's Method*/
{
    int it_sqrt=0;
    float a_sqrt = x/2;
    while ((abs((a_sqrt*a_sqrt)-(x))>=eps_sqrt) && (2.0*a_sqrt != 0) && (it_sqrt<=it))
    {
        a_sqrt = a_sqrt - ((a_sqrt*a_sqrt)-(x)/(2.0*a_sqrt));
        it_sqrt++;
    }
    return a_sqrt;
}

int main()
{
    printf("%.5f\n", sqrt(5));
    system ("pause");
}
```

i tried using the Newton's iteration method to find the square root on Python and it worked, perfectly well.
I'm new on C and I don't understand why this function didn't work for me.
Whenever I run it, it returns "-1.#INF0A"
Any help will  be appreciated.

---

**Edit:** I tried changin the eps to `0.000001` and it also didn't work.

Comment: I tried that but it still gives the same result

Comment: wrong macro function abs argument. see my answer.

Comment: don't use your own homebrew `abs` macro, it evaluates its argument twice. The C library has `fabs` for that. This usually a builtin, so the performance is the same but it is safe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double mysqrt(double x){
    double eps=pow(10,-10);
    double x0 = 0.0;
    double x1 = x/2.0;
    while(fabs(x1 - x0)>eps){
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = x0 + (x - x0*x0)/x0/ 2.0;
    }
    return x1;
}
```

macro expansion
`abs((a_sqrt*a_sqrt)-(x))`
expansion `(((a_sqrt*a_sqrt)-(x))>0 ? (a_sqrt*a_sqrt)-(x): -(a_sqrt*a_sqrt)-(x))`
NG: `-(a_sqrt*a_sqrt)-(x)`

`abs((a_sqrt*a_sqrt- x))`
expansion `(((a_sqrt*a_sqrt- x))>0 ? (a_sqrt*a_sqrt- x): -(a_sqrt*a_sqrt- x))`

rewrite
`#define abs(a) ((a)>0 ? a: -a)`
to
`#define abs(a) ((a)>0 ? a: -(a))`

Answer (score 4):

Changing this line:

```
                a_sqrt = a_sqrt - ((a_sqrt*a_sqrt)-(x)/(2.0*a_sqrt));
```

to

```
                a_sqrt = a_sqrt - ((a_sqrt*a_sqrt - x)/(2.0*a_sqrt));
```

works for me.

Comment: it worked but this doesn't follow the newton's method strictly

Comment: it's approximately the bisection method

Comment: Are you sure? It works for all integers from 0 to 100. Check the equations for Newton's method again.

Comment: it works but it is not the newton's method. the newton's method is
x = x - f(x)/f'(x)
thank you very much! i think C has its own precision problem, when i used the inbuilt function in the math.h library i got the same result.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use a bigger epsilon, maybe python uses doubles instead of floats.

Comment: Indeed. Epsilon for float should be more like 0.0000001 (7 decimal places)

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the rare cases where using `double` actually makes sense.
Note that the precision of float is significantly lower than eps_sqrt:

```
[mic@mic-nb tmp]$ cat tmp2.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double a = sqrtl(2.0);
    printf("%1.20f\n", a - (float) a);
}
[mic@mic-nb tmp]$ gcc tmp2.c; ./a.out
0.00000002420323430563
vs. your value of:
0.00000000000001
```

So your program will, in most cases, never terminate.